# Prove or disprove this statement about differentiability of two variable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The Statement:

> Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, even and differentiable function and $g'(0)=0$, let $f(x,y)=g(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}).$ Then $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$

**My attempt:** 
I wrote the definition of differentiability first: $f(0+\Delta x,0+\Delta y)-f(0,0) = f'_x(0,0)\Delta x+f'_y(0,0)\Delta y +\epsilon\sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$. 
I can see that theres some connection with $f(x,y)$ and the last part of the definition, so intuitively I think that there must be some trick to prove and not disprove (still not sure though). 
From here I'm not sure how to continue, I tried to do this: 

if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ then $f'_x(0,0)=g'(0)=0$ and in the same way $f'_y(0,0)=g'(0)=0$. 
So now I have to prove that $\epsilon \to 0$ in this: 
$f(\Delta x,\Delta y)-f(0,0)=\epsilon \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$ 

And here I got stuck, I know that both $\Delta x, \Delta y \to 0$, but I don't know stuff about $f$, and I tried to think how to use that $g$ is an even function but also didn't get any idea. 

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint : You need to use $g(x) \underset{x \to 0}{=} g(0) + g'(0)x  +o(x)$

Comment: the question is odd; the fact that $g$ is even is used to prove that $g'(0)=0$. This is a redundant assumption to make

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ahh yeah, as I'm translating the question from another language, I messed up a little, it was meant to be like "so $g'(0) = 0$", thanks for pointing that out, I even missed it understanding the question.

Comment: $\nabla f(p)=\frac{p}{\|p\|}g'(\|p\|)$. As $\frac{p}{\|p\|}$ is bounded and $\lim_{p\to0} g'(\|p\|)=0$, provided that $g'$ is continuous in $0$, we have $\nabla f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {f(h,k)-f(0,0)} {\sqrt {h^{2}+k^{2}}}=\frac {g(t)-g(0)} t$ where $t=\sqrt {h^{2}+k^{2}}$. Since $t \to 0$ as $(h,k) \to (0,0)$ we see that $\frac {f(h,k)-f(0,0)} {\sqrt {h^{2}+k^{2}}} \to 0$ $(h,k) \to (0,0)$. By definition $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and the derivative is the zero transformation from $\mathbb R^{2}$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks alot! I have a little question about the definition of differentiability for two variable functions, what you wrote is what I consider the definition for one variable functions, but I can see that you can reach it from the definition I wrote when $f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=0$ and dividing by the square root, is that what makes it differentiable or it's enough to show what you did without what I said?

Comment: @Pwaol Here is the definition: A linear trasformation $L(x,y)=ax+by$ is the derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ if $\frac {f(h,k)-f(0,0)-(ah+bk)} {\sqrt {h^{2}+k^{2}}} \to 0$ as $(h,k) \to (0,0)$. The coefficients $a$ and $b$ are the partial derivatives at the origin so I verified that the this limit holds when $a=b=0$.